# I want to insert data into two different database

Tags: database, codeigniter, opencart

I want to insert data into two different database.

Both the database are on different servers & both are different applications.

**First application** is of Codeigniter.

**Second application** id of Open Cart.

What should I do to insert the data into both database table.
should I am using nusoap or simple create second data connection and pass the value.
please help me out....

Comment: A tool like red-gate might be helpful.

Comment: Codeigniter version?

Comment: Codeigniter version :- 2,
and
Opencart version:- 1.5,

Comment: Are you trying to connect codeigniter database from opencart or opencart database from codeigniter or both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Database configuration:(you can can configure multiple database)

  ```
  //default/main database
  $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
  $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
  $db['default']['password'] = '';
  $db['default']['database'] = 'database1';
  $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
  $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
  $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
  $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
  $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
  $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
  $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
  $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE; 

  //another database
  $db['db2']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
  $db['db2']['username'] = 'root';
  $db['db2']['password'] = '';
  $db['db2']['database'] = 'database2';
  $db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
  $db['db2']['dbprefix'] = '';
  $db['db2']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
  $db['db2']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
  $db['db2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
  $db['db2']['cachedir'] = '';
  $db['db2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
  $db['db2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
  $db['db2']['swap_pre'] = '';
  $db['db2']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
  $db['db2']['stricton'] = FALSE;
  ```
- load the database

  `$this->db2 = $CI->load->database('db2', TRUE);`
- insert data using the db instance

  ```
  $data = array(
  'title' => 'My title' ,
  'name' => 'My Name' ,
  'date' => 'My date'
  );
  $this->db2->insert('mytable', $data);
  ```

  more info - http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/connecting.html

  here have an example of connecting two database in ci http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-connect-two-different-databases/